# WPF - How to fire MouseLeftButtonUp event for ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, combobox, mouseevent

I have a ComboBox who have to call a function that need the selectedItem of the ComboBox as parameter when the user select an item.
Because this event need to be fired even when the item doesn't change I can't use the SelectionChanged event. So to resolve this problem I wanted to use the MouseLeftButtonUp, but this event doesn't seems to work.

I have tried to use the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event, who is triggered, but the selectedItem of the ComboBox is only modified after the event, which is too late for me.

I have also tried the MouseLeftButtonDown event, but it's doesn't work either.

WPF :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                  PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Cb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                  MouseLeftButtonUp="Cb_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                  MouseLeftButtonDown="Cb_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                  SelectionChanged="Cb_SelectionChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# for testing :

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace WpfApp1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            cb.Items.Add("a");
            cb.Items.Add("b");
        }
        private void Cb_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("event : Preview mouse UP");
        }
        private void Cb_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("event : Mouse UP"); // Doesn't fire
        }
        private void Cb_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("event : Mouse DOWN"); // Doesn't fire either
        }
        private void Cb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("event : selection changed"); // Only fire if the selected item change
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I just want to know if it's possible to trigger the MouseLeftButtonUp event.

Comment: How about just [MouseUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.mouseup?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: MouseUp and MouseDown events don't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [mami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363778/mami), I have found the solution :

```cs
this.AddHandler(
    ComboBox.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(Cb_MouseLeftButtonUp),
    true
);
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168928/10736081)

Answer (score 0):

**DropDownClosed** will fire even if you select the element that is already selected.

Comment: This can be an alternative solution, but i would like to know why the MouseUp and MouseDown events are not fired for the ComboBox.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160995/wpf-slider-doesnt-raise-mouseleftbuttondown-or-mouseleftbuttonup . It is about a slider, but probably the same things applies here.